# Solve least squares regression in java

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am implementing a pandas DataFrame clone in Java and one of the functionalities I need is resampling. I have found a nice method to do it [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/what-is-an-algorithm-to-re-sample-from-a-variable-rate-to-a-fixed-rate). At the referenced link they use python, specifically the [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) function from numpy that takes a matrix `A` and a vector `b` exactly like in the formulas I need to implement.

Now I go to the [Apache Commons math website on Least squares](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/leastsquares.html) and the API seems nothing like `Least_squares(A, b)` but something completely different, and very complicated by the way.

I'd like to know how to solve the least squares non linear regression in java only by passing a matrix `A` and a vector `b` like in python.

Answer (score 4):

The Least Squares package in Apache Commons uses numeric minimization algorithms like *Gauss-Newton* and *Levenberg-Marquardt* for non-linear curve fitting (non-linear least squares).

`numpy.linalg.lstsq` on the other hand is for line fitting (linear least squares). The equivalent of `lstsq` in Apache commons is [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression).

In both cases you have a line fitting problem `y = mx + c`, where `x` and `y` are known vectors of equal length containing data points (multiple pairs of x.y scalar values). With `lstsq` you have to transform the problem to `y = Ap`, where `A = [[x 1]]` and `p = [[m], [c]]`. With `SimpleRegression` one option is to concatenate `x` and `y` in `double[][]` matrix with 2 columns and 1 data point per row.

Here is the same example mentioned in [lstsq docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) written for `SimpleRegression`:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creating regression object, passing true to have intercept term
        SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression(true);

        // passing data to the model
        // model will be fitted automatically by the class
        simpleRegression.addData(new double[][]{
                {0, -1},
                {1, 0.2},
                {2, 0.9},
                {3, 2.1}
        });

        // querying for model parameters
        System.out.println("slope = " + simpleRegression.getSlope());
        System.out.println("intercept = " + simpleRegression.getIntercept());
    }
}
```

And of course you get the same result

> slope = 1.0
>   intercept = -0.95